# There is a problem with this website’s security certificate

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, windows-7

I've a problem in my browser !,

I watched many solutions on youtube to fix this problem.

I did everything, I changed date and time of my computer.

I think this error occurs as a result of a browser that does not recognize the authority of the certificate.

I can browse all sites like "Google, Youtube, Gmail, stackoverflow, etc .." "except for this site" https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/id/management/ "

I use windows 7 home premium 64 bit,
Google chrome ->   last version,
IE -> 11

Please try to browse this site "https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/id/management/"

Comment: I try to browse the site and it can show in Chrome and IE [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix7UI.jpg). What is the result in your side? Does it show blank in the browser or you can't log in the site? Is there any error in the page or in console? Please provide the detail error information and result. Besides, you could try to clear browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Problem with this website's security certificate"** is a generic error message that Internet Explorer gives you when there is a problem establishing a secure connection (https://) to a website using the site's SSL certificate.

This error message can be caused by any number of issues. For example, here are some of the causes:

- Your computer and the website's server could not agree on cryptographic algorithms to use for the secure connection. This can sometimes happen for older versions of Internet Explorer.
- The authenticity of a website's SSL certificate could not be verified by a Certificate Authority (CA).

You did not provide enough detail in your question to figure out the **exact** cause of the issue. But, in this case, updating your web browser may help fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a common browser error that is not letting you visit that website with HTTPS.

I tested that website and it working fine in my browser. (Tested through Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE). So I think the issue is with your system.

- Try clearing the cache and cookies for that particular website
- Clear the SSL State from Internet Options
- Disable QUIC Protocol of Google Chrome

Source: https://aboutssl.org/fix-google-chrome-error-err_ssl_protocol_error/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download de certificate:
   https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.der
2. Right click on this file.
3. Install Cerficate
4. Next
5. Click on second opticn. (my windows on pt-br -"colocar todos os cerficiados no repositorio a seguir") Browser
6. Select = Autoridade de certificação Raiz confiável.
7. OK
8. Next
9. Finish